# getURLParameter(ID)

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, document-set, query-string

Lots of great posts on using the getURLParameter(ID) to populate a lookup column in a NewForm.aspx when coming from a list view web part on another page.  Here is my problem, the source url that I am querying does not have an explicit "ID=6" but instead since I am coming from a document set home page looks like this:`"...%2FSharePoint%2FProject%2520Document%2520Set%2FForms%2FProject%2Fdocsethomepage%2Easpx%3FID%3D6..."`  So the part that I am trying to parse or get the url parameter is `"FID%D6"` instead of simply `ID=6`.

I tried using this code which I got from a similar post (apologies for being unable to give credit to original poster) but did not successfully populate the ID.  Was only able to populate the Null result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this fetches the parameter from the current url
// CASE SENSITIVE
function getUrlParameter( name )
{
name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
if( results == null ) return "";
else return results[1];
}

function populateNewForm()
{
//Populate your field
//to know the element id of your field you use the IE dev tools
document.getElementById("Project_x0020_Name_c9c83d51-e59d-4fc8-b811-d8eee5fd6818_$LookupField").value = getUrlParameter("ID");
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("populateNewForm")
</script>
```

Any ideas on edits to use this code to parse this type of URL and/or any other existing solutions that anyone is aware of?  Here is my attempt to edit the code and decode the encoded url but it is not working:

// this fetches the parameter from the current url
// CASE SENSITIVE
var UrlParams = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");

var GetUrlParam = function ('ID')
{
    for (var i = 0; i

Comment: Karthik, thank you for your edits to improve my question, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the URL is just encoded, you could try decoding the URL before passing through the function, or try another function to get the URL. Its a standard javascript function not specific to SharePoint so there are many reference out there

https://html-online.com/articles/get-url-parameters-javascript/

Perform some debugging, as in instead of getting window.location.href set it to a string test = "https://testurl.com?ID=1" and see if it returns the expected results, and go from there

This is the function I use on the daily

```
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
```

Comment: Warwick, thank you for your response, so I will try to decode the URL before passing through the function and update with the result.

Comment: I was able to find many related posts which decode the url:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731778/get-query-string-parameters-url-values-with-jquery-javascript-querystring    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery-or-how-to-get-query-string-values-in-js/31412050   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161246/pass-value-to-newform-aspx-via-querystring but don't know js well enough to marry with the populate new form script that was my starting point. @Warwick W

Comment: Tried this but did not work, any ideas:
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUrlParameter(ID)
{ID = ID.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+ID+"([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
if( results == null ) return "8";
else return decodeURI(results[1]);
}function populateNewForm(){
//Populate SPListForm
document.getElementById("Project_x0020_Name_c9c83d51-e59d-4fc8-b811-d8eee5fd6818_$LookupField").value = getUrlParameter('ID');
}_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("populateNewForm")
</script>

Comment: what error are you getting/seeing?

Comment: comment out the field update for now and just write the output of the function to the console.log(getUrlParameter(ID)); - get that working and then do the second part to update list

Comment: I use this function almost everyday and never has an issues  ```function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};```

Comment: thanks for the responses and result is populating the default value which tells me that code is not successfully pulling the ID field.  I wonder whether since the ID is nested in the ?Source=https.... section of the URL if I need to use a different function, maybe search string instead of url parameter?  Does url parameter search the full url?  Also do I need to replace name in above code with "ID" (single quotes or double quotes?)  Thank you. @Warwick W

Comment: paste the code below into your site and I'm sure it will work, and go from there
`function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};

const itemID = getUrlParameter("ID");
alert(itemID);
`

Comment: Thanks and added populate newform function at end but didnt work: getUrlParameter(name) { name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]'); var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)'); var results = regex.exec(location.search); return results === null ? '8' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' ')); }; const itemID = getUrlParameter("ID"); alert(itemID);
}function populateNewForm()
{document.getElementById("Project_x0020_Name_c9c83d51-e59d-4fc8-b811-d8eee5fd6818_$LookupField").value = getUrlParameter("ID");}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("populateNewForm")

Comment: thank you so much for the code, I am sure it would work were I not using a SharePoint document set and having to pull the Document Set ID from the ?Source= section of a very long and encoded url and then populate that ID in a new form.  Based on further research it appears that perhaps ID is reserved for another value on the newform.aspx page and therefore I am unable to populate.  Further, I am certain that this can be done but it is subject to the constrainsts and idiosyncrasies of working with SharePoint.  Thanks again.  I will follow up soon if I find anything useful.@Warwick W

Comment: At the very least I am able to populate a default value when specified.  So for example if I replace null ?'' with null ? '8' it succesfully populates the Document Set that corresponds with ID=8

Comment: The fact that the null value is populating tells me that though the ID is there in the URL it is not getting found and/or poulated.  Perhaps it is a timing issue and I need to add/use the window.onload or $(document).ready function?

Comment: entered this in console and returns 20, 21, 22, etc.  Appears to be pulling a different ID than url: function getUrlParameter(name) {name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '8' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}function populateNewForm()
{document.getElementById("Project_x0020_Name_c9c83d51-e59d-4fc8-b811-d8eee5fd6818_$LookupField").value = getUrlParameter('ID');
}_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("populateNewForm")

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this solved my problem and many thanks to Warwick and Alex B:

setTimeout(function(){
    var theValue = GetUrlKeyValue("ID",false,unescape(GetUrlKeyValue("Source")));
    document.getElementById("Project_x0020_Name_c9c83d51-e59d-4fc8-b811-d8eee5fd6818_$LookupField").value = theValue;
},1000);